# Is there a way to get 'Day of the Week'

Tags: sql, sql-server

The function `DAYOFTHEWEEK` is unfortunately not built into SQL Server - are there any equivalents? I've only been able to find functions that provide the day number (1-31), but not the actual day name.

Answer (score 1):

Below should do. The parameter should be slightly different from `datepart`. Use `W` instead of `week`

```
select datename(W, '2020-02-02' )
```

Comment: Hmm, I just tried that and it returned the value of the day (1-31), and not the name.

Comment: @CluelessBSA That's weird. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b20e7c74e0c124a0be98e8f93b097aa2

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has two functions, depending on whether you want a string or a number:

```
[datepart(weekday, col)][1]
[datename(weekday, col)][1]
```

You can also use `format()` with the `'dddd'` specification:

```
format(col, 'dddd')
```

This is convenient, because `'ddd'` gives you a three-letter abbreviation.  And `format()` allows a third argument where you can specify the culture -- such as enforcing that the value is in English.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, it looks like it was the 'weekday' argument was what I had missing!

Answer (score 0):

use `datename` instead of `datepart` with the same parameters to get the name instead of the number

Comment: Hmm, I just tried that and it returned the value of the day (1-31), and not the name.